# Optimization of UI (.xml files) and java codes in android

Tags: android

when I am going to develop an android application. For better performance of my application what are necessary steps. In another word how to optimize my codes and .xml files, in best way. And what are steps to remember when I am going to use huge set of variables.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a pretty broad question. I suggest going through some of the [articles in the developer resources](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/index.html). They cover many topics, from avoiding memory leaks to reusing XML layouts.